# Should I compress python files in Django?

Tags: python, django, compression, minify

I know that I should compress frontend files (HTML, CSS, JS) to increase the security and loading speed of a website.

But how about the backend files (for example Python)? Should I compress them too? Do I get any benefits from doing that?

Comment: Compression is useful when files have to be transferred over the network.. there would be no benefit by doing that to source code.

Comment: On a modern machine compressing with gzip even on the lowest setting occupies about 1 CPU per 1Gbps link and adds a noticeable latency. This is why it is a good idea to pre-compress static files and send the compress version, but rather bad to compress dynamically created responses since they have to be compressed every time, in real time.

Answer (score 2):

I've been developing Django applications for the past 10 years, and I've never worried about compressing the actual python files since these files are not going to be transferred to the client. However, you actually can compress the responses sent from your Django server by using the built-in [GZipMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip) which compresses content for browsers that understand GZip compression (all modern browsers).

The process is as simple as adding the following line to your `settings.py`

```py
Either by enabling the middleware in settings.py by adding:

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware,
    ...
)
```

> **Note:** This middleware should be placed before any other middleware that need to read or write the response body so that compression happens afterward.

This is what I usually do on the backend side, and then I just focus on making the server-side processing faster.

Comment: Note that from the documentation it said this `Security researchers recently revealed that when compression techniques (including GZipMiddleware) are used on a website, the site may become exposed to a number of possible attacks.` so there is a security problem when using this ...

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow Good note, I recommend reading the paper and the webpage mentioned in Django's documentation to assess the situation.